# Why aren't the enemies scaling with my level in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Borderlands 2, Playthrough 2. I tried farming Mobley and Gettle, and even though I reached level 40, they remained at a low level. In all the videos I've seen, they were at the player's level. I understand that it's the level of the area, because in my vending machines sold items are level 34. Question: why so others have region level scaling up with the player, but I don't?

Comment: Are you playing with another player? What difficulty is their playthrough set at?